# Login failure using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Any help will be very much appreciated.

I'm trying to programmatically log in to [www.penson.com](http://www.penson.com/) using my user and password credentials.

When doing so using an explorer (Chrome, for this matter), the login link is the following:
https://online.penson.com/(q3lsh145vubfki45dl1tr1yc)/Default.aspx?LoginInProgress=YES

After logging in using this link, the link is the following:
https://online.penson.com/(q3lsh145vubfki45dl1tr1yc)/Default.aspx?LI=Y

and from there I continue working with the web site…
Of course this link is changing every time I'm entering the web site, containing a different some kind of a "Guid".

Now, what I'm doing in my code is the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "https://online.penson.com/Default.aspx?LoginInProgress=YES");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myUser, myPassword);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = 0;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

the 'result' string looks like this (HTML structure that I have edited for simpler display):

> Object moved to href='/(cls10ljriatq2luvwyzo4eyq)/Default.aspx?LoginInProgress=YES'

From this string I have extracted the 'href' sub string and then I have tried to create another request with this full address:

https://online.penson.com/(cls10ljriatq2luvwyzo4eyq)/Default.aspx?LoginInProgress=YES

This one doesn't work, and parsing the stream response indicates I'm still in the login web page, and haven't actually continued forward the next web page.

I'm trying to find out what is wrong with the code. I guess my thinking of getting the "Guid" and parse it to the login address in not an accurate one.

Can someone point me to a certain solution?

Comment: did you send your cookies with that second request?

Comment: I guess I didn't... how do I send them?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and compare the successfull requests (made with some browser) and the failing requests... then mimic the successfull requests in code by removing/adding whatever needed, very often [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) are one of the "culprits" in such situations - sometimes it is a specific referer or similar...

Besides the coding part: check whether automatically logging in this way is forbidden by their terms/conditions!